# Visual Studio 2015 - Microsoft Developer account app list not retrieved

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I've developed a cordova app and I wanted to publish it to the Windows Store. A Windows Developer Account (company account) has been bought and associated with my Microsoft Work Account, and I can login via the browser and reserve the app name, start a submission, etc. 
To build the .appxupload file required by Windows Store, I was referring the third part of [Packaging UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps) document. However, when I open the Create App Package option, at the "Select an app name" screen, the app name I had reserved via the browser is not displayed, nor is it reserving a new app name. It always displays a network error, as seen in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4tNO.jpg).

> An unexpected network error has occurred. The app list cannot be refreshed. Please retry by pressing the Refresh button.

Is there anything else I have to do to connect the account to my VS?

PS: The logged in accounts (in VS, and the browser dev account) are the same, I've checked multiple times. There is no issue with my LAN connection, I'm using the same connection everywhere with no problems.

Comment: I had strange problems with registering my developer license. There I got always  an error 0x80072f8f.

In my case it helped to execute once:
netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie

Comment: From the error message, it seems VS has failed trying to retrieve the app names. Could you please turn off the VS and try it again after a period of time?

Comment: Both these methods did not work. Not sure whether this is important, but the Win Developer account was bought with another account (Company account), and then shared with my account. There are no problems connecting to the Win Dev account from VS with the account it was bought with.